# why after I deployed my sails app on Heroku, some custom css attribution can not show on the screen

Tags: css, node.js, heroku, deployment, sails.js

I am quite new with Heroku and just deployed my sails.js on Heroku. After deployment I can open the website but I found that some of css attribution can not be presented after I deployed it on Heroku. But it is so confused that if I start it on my localhost, it works well. For example, in my custome.js, I assign a picture

```
 .carousel-inner {
 background: url('/images/banner.jpg');

 these are my css files in layout.ejs
 <link="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
 <link="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/select2.min.css">
 these are my javascript files in layout.ejs
  <!-- PRELOAD SCRIPTS -->
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <!--SCRIPTS-->
  <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ejs/ejs_production.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ejs/view.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
 <!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

to my carousel-inner class, but I can not found this picture after I deployed it on Heroku. And also I used dataTable.js, but it can not work on Heroku and works well on my localhost. There are other attributes that can not been presented after I deployed it on Heroku. Is there something wrong? I would really appreciate your help if you can help me!

Comment: Have you placed your Assets ( js, css, images, etc ) in `assets/` directory ?!

Comment: @Thank you so much for your reply! I have put it in my assets/ directory. But I am so confused not only it can not show the picture, there are other css attributes that not work. For example I used dataTables.bootstrap.js and dataTables.boostrap.css, they also not work

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late, but in case somebody else needs the solution, this is what worked for me:
Make sure your .sailsrc file has the following:

`{ 
  "hooks": { 
    "grunt": false 
  },
  "paths": {
    "public": "assets"
  }
}`

With this in place, I could see custom stylesheets both when sails app is running locally, and when it's deployed to Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your css code is error free using a css validator like [CSSLint](http://csslint.net/). In production css is minified and uglified so erroneous code may run fine on localhost but in minified form it behaves unexpectedly.